# Alterar o ícone do App Android

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um app no Android Studio e ao executar o app no smartphone, o ícone que aparece é o do próprio Android. Como faço para alterar esse ícone por um que tenho no meu computador?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basta substituir os ícones que estão presentes na pasta `res/mipmap`.

O ícone, no caso, chama-se `ic_launcher` e `ic_launcher_round`. O segundo utiliza bordas arredondadas, é um ícone redondo.

Você pode substituir eles ou colocar o seu ícone novo com um nome diferente. Se você fizer isto, basta alterar o `AndroidManifest` na TAG `<Application>`.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon_name" <!-- icone aqui -->
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/icon_name_rounded" <!-- icone aqui -->
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Você pode utilizar o atributo `roundIcon` assim como também pode removê-lo, se caso não queira utilizá-lo.

Você também pode criar ícones utilizando este site: [Asset Studio: Icon Launcher](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)

Você pode exportar sua imagem para o site, definir estilos (bordas, sombras...) e ele vai te gerar os ícones em suas devidas dimensões (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, ...).

É bem útil! :)

Comment: Perfeito itscorey. Muito obrigado.